# Display events on a Calendar on Android

Tags: android, calendar

I want to have a Calendar with a Month view displaying all the days and events on each day. 
I found CalendarView, but it doesn't really display events on the way I want.
I kept researching and checking lots of results, until I came across a entire app that does that called [SimpleMobileTools's Simple-Calendar](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar/). Here's how they display events on a Month view Calendar, if you didn't understand what I'm looking for yet:

[image: SimpleMobileTools's Simple-Calendar app]

Though, their app has way too many features plus it's an entire app. I thought there should be something like a CalendarView (not necessarily native) that I could just plug-and-play adding my events and having it displaying them on a Calendar. I thought this should be a very common need for developers (to have a month view calendar displaying events to their users) but since I've searched so much and found nothing like that, I'm here to ask.

Does anyone knows a simpler way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView?

```
<CalendarView
   android:id="@+id/simpleCalendarView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> The exact appearance and interaction model of this widget may vary between OS versions and themes (e.g. Holo versus Material), but in general a user can select a date by tapping on it and can scroll or fling the calendar to a desired date.

[image: ]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiDdw.png)

References:

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/calendarview

https://www.journaldev.com/22321/android-calendar-view

---

Here is the 3rd party library I believe is used in your screenshot:

https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar

It creates a custom view, that potentially you can re-use:

https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/simplemobiletools/calendar/pro/views/MonthView.kt

Here are some alternatives:

http://applandeo.com/blog/material-calendar-view-customized-calendar-widget-android/

https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar

Comment: I mean a month view like CalendarView, but I also want to display events on this calendar. You may have a look on the example on the screenshot I posted when describing the question.

Comment: Here is the source for you to add events: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java?q=CalendarView

Comment: Updated with a link to the code from your screenshot & some alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like you haven't read my question descriptions since some of the links you've shared are the same that I shared :-) But I'll have a look on those other links too. Appreciated!

Comment: I did, I was confused that you called it an app, when it actually has the source code in there to do it :-)

Comment: @leoneboaventura If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @blundel I do not think you did fully answer the question. However, you did put a lot of effort into your answer so definitely deserve a vote up. I actually think there is a need for a callendar like leoneboaventura is asking for, and I am surprised after all this time the Google's Android one is so limited.